# How to create a holy, happy earth without human death?

Tags: humans, geography, earth, futurology, civilization

Consider if I removed human death from earth, but still people will get older. If we find a way to stop human death, we could face a lot of problems such as **increased crime (since no one can die), population issues, food problems, etc.**

I removed only human death from the earth and now I want to make earth more holy.

What are the necessary rules/action that should be taken to achieve this?

Update:

Since we are removing only human death from earth people still people will get hungry, wound, pain.  Except human death everything else is same I.e heart attack, cancer everything is same as now.  So degree of inconvenience, pain will increase but no death for human.  In that case how can we act effectively to decrease the inconvenience, pain that caused by immorality.

Holy - here I'm referring it as a less crime, less inconvenience world.

In short, we have to bring back life balance like the current situation.  Only change is there will be no human death.

Comment: For a world where people age indefinitely but don't die, read the legend of Tithonus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithonus

Comment: Are you asking how to find immortality?

Comment: No. If we achieve that (immortality) how the world should be ? @HDE226868

Comment: I think overpopulation would be the largest issue... The next logical step would be terraforming the earth, followed by an expansion to other bodies in our solar system. You'd also have a serious food shortage issue - I'd think overcrowding and starvation would make your population very unhappy. I'd start colonizing other planets, and leaving earth to farm food for those planets. Then you've solved overcrowding, and starvation.

Comment: What is "holy"?

Comment: That's one theme in the *Queendom of Sol* series of novels. The early ones  deal with what the kids experience if the parents never make way; towards the end it shows serious resource depletion.

Comment: 1) You need to clarify. Is death impossible, i.e., cut off head it regrows, or simply no death by old age, or no death by natural causes, i.e., no more death from heart attacks, cancer, etc. 2) What do you mean by holiness? Define it for the question.

Comment: Death is impossible.  Can you die of starvation?  Pollution?  Decapitation?  Miscarriage?  Abortion?  You still get older.  What happens when you are 200?  Can you still stand?  And I too want to what you mean by "holy".

Comment: If you can't die from lack of food, wouldn't food problems be reduced to a mere inconvenience?

Comment: @celtschk not really, though you wouldn't die, you would still lose body mass and be in pain from the hunger. It would be a unending torture that you couldn't be released from. There are also diseases and weaknesses that come with old age, which would build up making you wish you were dead.

Comment: @Brythan still this question not fit to community standards?

Comment: This still seems on the weak side.  If someone doesn't eat for twenty years, what happens?  You can't say that it's exactly like now except that they don't die -- during most of that period they would be rotting because they were dead.  I.e. what happens after they would have died?  Similarly, what happens if someone is cremated or vaporized by an atomic bomb.  What's left to be alive?  When can't someone die?  From conception?  From birth?  Some point in between?  I.e. does abortion work as birth control?

Comment: If you want more help you might consider posting in the [sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/635/2113) in meta or posting another question here about "What would be the physical consequences of a world without death?" with most of the information from here.  As stands, I think there are too many ways of implementing a world without death.  So answers may come from different assumptions.

Comment: I don't aware of the sandbox.Thanks for the info. @Brythan

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at all certain what you mean by "holiness", or how you would quantify it, but the most obvious action is to suppress the production of sex hormones, particularly testosterone. This will have two effects. First, it will cut down the birth rate enormously, and we need that to avoid winding up standing cheek to cheek over the entire globe as we starve. Second, it will be make everybody much less aggressive, and I assume you associate that with being holy.